# Angular ngview and nginclude breaks css

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am creating and admin page using  [this template](http://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE/). I am using Angular along with it.

The Problem if I user ngview and nginclude the css and some js is not working properly. Especially in css if we use these directives the parent child relation in css breaks.

Example: `body> .classname`  breaks because body is outside ngview and class is inside ngview. Is there any workaround for this?

I cant spend time on building my own template.

here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh35gsdp/1/) for example structure.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Did you first read my question properly? Why you people going on minus it?

Comment: That link is not my site. Thats what I am using.

Comment: This is in my opinion a fully legitimate question. 
Using Angular result in the creation of extraneous dom node that serve no semantic purpose (ng-include, etc). This breaks separation of concerns, and makes it impossible in css to rely on parent-child relationship, and siblings relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you use the wrong selector. `body > .classname` means : target .classname elements that are **direct children** of body.

Some docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Seeing your Fiddle :

```
<body>
    <div ngview>
        <div ng-include="'heading.html'">       
        </div>
        <div>
            Content
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Elements contained in heading.html will never be direct children of body.**

**So use : `body .classname`**

*FYI : CSS rules are applied to the whole HTML document (no matter when its parts are generated). If it breaks, that's surely because it's the wrong selector.*